# While installing ReactJs, i got Require post install error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, require, post-install

Firstly i install nodejs and then using npm i install package name create-react-app globally and then created react app using npx create-react-app app-name , i got the following error:

```
core-js@2.6.11 postinstall PATH
node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
core-js@3.6.5 postinstall
node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
core-js-pure@3.6.5 postinstall
node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
```

Comment: This could help - https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8441#issuecomment-583197435

Comment: No, this not helped out